# Flexbox with center valign and allow expandable content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

First of all, the first snippet below is the problem I'm trying to fix.

Note that this was working perfectly fine **IF** `display: flex;` is applied to `body`.

However, I do not want to apply style to `body` which will break Google Web Cache layout.

** More explanation after the first snippet*

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 0; }
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.navigation {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.content {
  background-color: #ff0;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0.6rem 0 1.2rem;
}
.container {
  background-color: #f0f;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 120rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}
.centered {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.long-content {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <nav class="navigation">.navigation</nav>
  <div class="content">
    <section class="container centered">
      <div class="long-content">.long-content</div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">.footer</footer>
</main>
```

So, removing `display: flex;` raised this issue:

- `section` within `.content` does not have the height spanning across `.content`

Trying to fix it with `position: relative` on `.content` and `position: absolute` on `.centered` fixed the height issue but raised:

- Width of `.centered` does not span across `.content` which can be easily fixed with `left:0;right:0;`
- Height does not flow with content in `section` (I'm out of idea here)

Was it wrong to use `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to patch the original issue?
If so, what is the more suitable solution?

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 0; }
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.navigation {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.content {
  background-color: #ff0;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0.6rem 0 1.2rem;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  background-color: #f0f;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 120rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}
.centered {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.long-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <nav class="navigation">.navigation</nav>
  <div class="content">
    <section class="container centered">
      <div class="long-content">.long-content</div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">.footer</footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I continued looking for solution and quickly noticed that I have shallow knowledge about flexbox itself so I went ahead and played with [Flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com).

After completing all the levels, I noticed that I can align everything without `position: absolute` by just using `justify-content` on `.wrapper`.

Below is my solution for my silly issue.

If you remove `height` of `.long-content`, `.centered` will continue to get aligned vertically.

Thank you froggies and shout out to [Codepip](https://codepip.com)!

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 0; }
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navigation {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.content {
  background-color: #ff0;
  margin: 0.6rem 0 1.2rem;
}
.container {
  background-color: #f0f;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 120rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}
.centered {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.long-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <nav class="navigation">.navigation</nav>
  <div class="content">
    <section class="container centered">
      <div class="long-content">.long-content</div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">.footer</footer>
</main>
```